# Android: Why subtitle in ListView not grey?

Tags: android, listview

I use latest Android Studio and SDK. In preview & real device i see this:

[image]

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myappname.view.AboutActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewAbout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How i make subtitle text color is gray? Like this:

[image]

Comment: where is your single row layout(xml)

Comment: android:textColor="your_color" , to your subtitle in [single_item.xml]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb and assume that you're using the row layout `simple_list_item_2.xml` (based on the screenshot) which gives you two rows. The *problem*, if you may call it that, is that depending on the SDK version, the [styling](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Properties) for this layout has changed.

On [**SDK 23**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html), it looks like this:

[image]

However, on say [**SDK 19**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/android-4.4.html), it looks like this:

[image]

#### Why?

To understand this we first need to take a look at the xml that generates the rows from  `simple_list_item_2.xml`, you'll see it's a pretty simple layout that uses the now deprecated view `TwoLineListItem` but that's just a plus on why to use your custom layout.

```
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:mode="twoLine"
    android:paddingStart="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">

    <TextView android:id="@id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <TextView android:id="@id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary" />

</TwoLineListItem>
```

The reason is because of the way the style `textAppearanceListItemSecondary` is resolved in each SDK version. The style is what gives the text the size, the color, etc. The evolution of the interface in Android has given birth to a huge ecosystem of themes and relying on the default styling will result in inconsistencies like the one you stumbled upon.

#### What to do about it?

You should use your own layout for this to allow for uniform styling across versions. To do so, please refer to any of the [multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=custom%20layout%20listview%20android) covering this matter. But in short it just means creating a layout file, call it for example `custom_row.xml` and having the layout look exactly as you please. This also gives you total control over placement of the items, extra Views that you may need, and overhead in terms of coding is minimal compared to the `SimpleAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter` that perhaps you were using.

#### Note

You should consider moving your code towards `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

> You can set Textview property
>    `android:textColor="@color/grey"`
>
> in you Adapter layout to change colour of your sub item
>
> Hope this will help